# Problemas con Deploy NodeJS a Heroku

Tags: javascript, nodejs, sqlite, heroku

Tengo esta situación, tengo un proyecto montado en Heroku y lo actualizo vía git, pero de un tiempo para acá no me deja hacerle `git push heroku master`
me tira este error, he tratado de hacer varias cosas, pero el error persiste , ¿alguien sabe a qué se deba?

```
      npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
       npm ERR! errno 1
       npm ERR! sqlite3@4.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
       npm ERR! Exit status 1
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.0.6 install script.
       npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ZJa3F/_logs/2019-11-16T01_27_11_336Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed

       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys

       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/

       Love,
       Heroku

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Configuración del puerto en la aplicación:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000); //puerto y asì 
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => { 
          console.log('App listening on port ${app.get('port')}'); 
//console.log(hostname) 
});
```

Comment: Como tienes configurado el puerto en tu aplicacion? Pregunto, porque una vez tuve un error al deployar en Heroku y era porque el puerto debe estar configurado de una forma especifica. Podrias incluir la configuracion?

Comment: asi  `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 4000); //puerto` y asì `app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('App listening on port ${app.get('port')}');
    //console.log(hostname)
  });
`

Comment: A mi me sucedió hace un tiempo y repare con el siguiente comando `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g sqlite3` espero te sirva. Esto también puede sucede si actualizas nodejs porque sqllite3 solo soporta Node.js v4.x, v6.x, v8.x, v10.x, v11.x and v12.x así que también puedes verificar tu versión.

Comment: estoy usando v8 , ya corri ese comando y actualizé pero nada ... sigo teniendo `remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the sqlite3@4.0.6 install script.`

Comment: Intentar desplegar a traves de Travis CI. Configura Heroku dentro de travis, a ver que te dice. pero parece ser un tema de versiones, actualiza con maven todas las dependencias, quiza hiciste algun upgrade y te protesta. Pasale por sonarqube y bettercodehub y mira la calidad del codigo.
Otra opcion seria revisar el historial de commit desde que te da el fallo, a ver que cambio en el commit desde que tienes el error. Suerte.

Comment: Has probado a borrar el package.lock o yarn.lock ?

Comment: @AdolfoOnrubia si intente, pero cada que lo intento subir el build falla

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim intenta utilizar una version diferente de sqlite3, ejempo sqlite3@4.1.0

Comment: Tu applicacion funciona correctamente en tu servidor local?
Si es asi puedes confirmar la version de nodejs que tienes en heroku, y la que tienes instalada localmente?

Comment: Normalmente a mi el error me lo marca mas arriba del `npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE` busca todos los errores en el log

Comment: ¿Podrías marcar la respuesta a la que le otorgaste los 50 puntos de recompensa como acepada? Ayudarás a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya ha pasado mucho y habia olvidado contestar esta pregunta, pero en resumen, el problema aqui es que estaba tratando de subir en mi commit la carpeta **node_modules**, asi que la respuesta fue muy simple.

> git rm -r --cached node_modules

Y listo. Todo bien con mi deploy.

Answer (score 4):

Quiero empezar indicando que esta respuesta no intenta responder el porque del error, sino que apunta a señalar porque no es recomendable utilizar `SQLite` en `Heroku`.

A continuación cito un fragmento traducido del artículo [SQLite on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3):

> [...] `SQLite` se ejecuta en la memoria y realiza una copia de seguridad de su almacén de datos en archivos en el disco. Si bien esta estrategia funciona bien para el desarrollo, la pila Cedar de Heroku tiene un [sistema de archivos efímero](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Puede escribirle y leerlo, pero el contenido se borrará periódicamente. **Si usara `SQLite` en `Heroku`, perdería toda su base de datos al menos una vez cada 24 horas.**
>
> Incluso si los discos de `Heroku` fueran persistentes ejecutando `SQLite`, no encajaría bien. Como `SQLite` no se ejecuta como un servicio, cada banco de pruebas ejecutaría una copia de ejecución separada. Cada una de estas copias necesita su propia tienda con respaldo de disco. Esto significaría que cada `dyno` que alimenta su aplicación tendría un conjunto diferente de datos ya que los discos no están sincronizados.[...]

En otras palabras, salvo algún caso de uso muy especial, no es una buena idea utilizar `SQLite` en `Heroku`.

Comment: En cierto modo no es la respuesta... pero a la vez dejando de usar SQLite y usando otra base de datos se evita este problema y otros posteriores, me parece un buen aporte

Comment: no estoy usando sqlite, viene como parte de las librerías, ya he trato de desintalar sqlite desde npm , pero mi error persiste.

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim es difícil saber porque no te funciona sin tener acceso al código. Igualmente creo que no es posible utilizar `SQLite` en `Heroku` (_no lo he probado, pero en todos links donde se habla sobre el tema dicen que no se puede_).

Comment: @Marcos algo en particular que me sugieras?

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim ¿usaste un template/proyecto-base puntual para inciar le desarrollo? Si es así, tendrás el link?

Comment: @Marcos no no use solo express y uso rutas

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim, ¿que librerias estas usando?